# Selecting last ID value of the same day

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a sample table as you can see below

| ID | Date | Info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15.02.2020 | a |
| 2 | 15.02.2020 | b |
| 1 | 15.02.2020 | c |
| 1 | 15.02.2020 | d |
| 3 | 15.02.2020 | e |
| 1 | 16.02.2020 | f |
| 3 | 16.02.2020 | g |
| 3 | 16.02.2020 | h |

I need to create a select statement that show me the last row of every ID in the same day.
As you can see below.

| ID | Date | Info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 15.02.2020 | b |
| 1 | 15.02.2020 | d |
| 3 | 15.02.2020 | e |
| 1 | 16.02.2020 | f |
| 3 | 16.02.2020 | h |

How can I manage it in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select max(t2.id)
              from t t2
              where t2.info = t.info and t2.date = t.date
             );
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by info, date order by id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```